# how to resolve error while using cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, sudoku, opencv

i am a beginner in opencv. i was working on a project of Sudoku solver. at first i was working in extracting the Sudoku grid from the Sudoku. i successfully extracted it and find out the maximum box in the image(obviously the biggest box will be the Sudoku grid). but when i was trying to change the image shape according to the requirement(i.e. croping the image according the size of the sudoku grid) with the help of cv2.getperspective(pts1,pts2) i was getting the error.
here below is the code that is working fine.

```
import numpy as np
def get_sudo_rid(name,size):
    img=name
    original=img.copy()
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    graymain=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    ath=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(graymain,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,39,10)

    contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(ath,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    area=[]
    maxarea=0
    cnt=contours[0]
    for i in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(i)>maxarea:
            cnt=i
            maxarea=cv2.contourArea(i)
    blank= np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

    image=cv2.drawContours(blank,[cnt],-1,(255,255,255),5)
    edges=cv2.Canny(image,40,150)
    lines=cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,100)

    createhor=[]
    createver=[]
    created=[]
    anglediff=10
    rhodiff=10
    flag=0
    count = 2
    for line in lines:
        for(rho,theta) in line:
            flag=0
            for (rho1,theta1) in created:
                if(abs(rho-rho1) < rhodiff and abs(theta-theta1)<anglediff):
                    flag=1
            if(flag==0):
                a=np.cos(theta)
                b=np.sin(theta)
                xo=a*rho
                yo=b*rho
                x1=int( xo + 1000*(-b))
                y1=int( yo + 1000*(a))
                x2=int( xo + 1000*(-b))
                y2=int( yo +1000*(a))
                d=np.linalg.norm(np.array((x1,y1,0))-np.array((x2,y2,0)))
                cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

                m=abs(1/np.tan(theta))
                if(m<1):
                    createhor.append((rho,theta))
                else:
                    createver.append((rho,theta))

    points=[]
    for (rho,theta) in createhor:
        for (rho1,theta1) in createver:
            if(rho,theta)!=(rho1,theta1):
                a=[[np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta)],[np.cos(theta1),np.sin(theta1)]]
                b=[rho,rho1]
                cos=np.linalg.solve(a,b)
                if list(cos) not in points:
                    points.append(list(cos))

    points.sort()


    if(points[0][1]>points[1][1]):
        points[0],points[1]=points[1],points[0]
    if(points[-1][1] < points[-2][1]):
        points[-2],points[-1] = points[-1], points[-2]
points[1],points[2] = points[2],points[1]
    for i in points:
        images=cv2.circle(image,(int(i[0]),int(i[1])),4,(0,0,255),-1)


    pts1 = np.float32(points)
    pts2 = np.array([[0, 0], [size, 0], [0, size], [size, size]], np.float32)
    #pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [size, 0], [0, size], [size, size]])
    print(pts2)
```

till here my code is working fine.
but when i added the line

`M= cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)`

i got the below error:

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'cv::getPerspectiveTransform'`

Actually i am taking help in this project from github, and in his project he send size = 900 as a parameter, for all the images, and as i didn't understand why he did that so i copied the same.

Comment: Can you show what is the value and shape of `pts1`? I'm almost certain it is larger than a 4 x 2 matrix, and that's what's causing the error.

Comment: size of the image that i  have imported is :- (480, 640, 3)                   size of the list pts1 is :- (28,2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `pts1` must be a 4 x 2 matrix, not a 28 x 2. What you have to do is to get the outermost corners of the grid, which must be a float32 array of shape (4, 2), then get the perspective transform matrix, and finally apply it to the remaining points.

```py
dst = np.float32([[0, 0], [size, 0], [size, size], [0, size]])
# perspective transform = matrix transformation
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(outer_grid_corners, dst)
# apply transformation to all the other points
transformed_pts = cv2.warpPerspective(pts1, M)
```

Note that your `outer_grid_corners` must be ordered in a clockwise manner.